# Audio player is uninitialized Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to "touch" to the audio player in KikiAudioPlayer. Here is my view from where I want to do that.

```
class AudioBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nowPlayingSongLabel: UILabel!
    
    var kikiAudioPlayer = KikiAudioPlayer()
    
    @IBAction func playPauseButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let playImage = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")
        if playPauseButton.currentImage == playImage {
            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
            kikiAudioPlayer.play()
        } else {
            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
            kikiAudioPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the snippet of "KikiAudioPlayer" and declaration of the audio player.

```
class KikiAudioPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func play() {
        audioPlayer.play()
        delegate?.audioPlayerPlayingStatusChanged(isPlaying: true)
        updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateDelegate))
        updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
        setWaiting(to: false)
    }
     func pause() {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        delegate?.audioPlayerPlayingStatusChanged(isPlaying: false)
        updater.invalidate()
        setWaiting(to: true)
    }

}
```

When the button pressed my breakpoint said that. It means that I press the button nothing changes.

```
po kikiAudioPlayer.audioPlayer <uninitialized>
```

[image]

The question is why the audio player in AudioBarView is uninitialized if I created an instance of KikiAudioPlayer.

I didn't provide any asset to the player(it's not important) because the audio player is working fine but the problem is that can't pause and play it.

I've tried to clean the build folder but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue with this line of code:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

AVAudioPlayer doesn't have `init()` listed as a valid initializer. Even though you can use it without compliler warning. The official document shows four separate initializers, all of which take at least one parameter.

I sugguest you checking out https://www.onooks.com/psa-avaudioplayer-alloc-init-crashes-in-ios-13-1-and-avaudioplayer/ this blog for more information.

Updated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer

Comment: I have read the article but I didn't understand what I need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: changing ```var player = AVAudioPlayer()``` to ```var player: AVAudioPlayer!```? Does it help? I don't know the full logic only by the code snippet you provided.

Comment: Yes, I did it before but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than I think. I deleted the declaration of the audio player in KikiAudioPlayer and added it in the App delegate.

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```